# Why mixed GC could not clear memory while Full DC did?

Tags: java, java-8, g1gc

Running G1GC (Java 8) with below

```
MaxGCPauseMillis=100
InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30
G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=85
```

and memory is 115 GB.

I notice that there was a Full GC and it brought down memory from 111GB to 65 GB. Prior to Full GC there were few mixed GC but that was unable to clear memory. Is there any other parameter I should set?

Comment: In general, decisions about garbage collection are the runtime's responsibility.  You shouldn't ever have to think about GC, and if you do, there are patterns like Object Pools that are designed to mitigate GC problems.

Comment: If mixed GC could always reclaim all memory, the feature of doing a full GC did not exist. And if there was a magic option that improves the performance of every application, that option was already the default.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Promptly returning unused memory to the operating system is an OpenJDK 12 feature for the G1 collector:

- [JEP 346: Promptly Return Unused Committed Memory from G1](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/346) [(tracking issue)](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8204089)

You are observing the limitation described in the proposal: only full GCs return memory to the operating system, mixed/minor GCs do no ot.  Also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53921518/8316315).

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to see whether below options will help. 
 G1OldCSetRegionThresholdPercent=20   G1MixedGCCountTarget=12

Comment: Only indirectly, if it happens to increase the frequency of full GCs (which will make G1 perform poorly).